# Creation of a timer thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread

def hello():
    print("hello, world")
    t = threading.Timer(3.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print current_thread().name 

hello()
```

> This will create a new thread periodically every 3 seconds. I want to know whether the created thread be expired and then again new thread will be created.? I can see the thread name as "Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3" and so on be created. I want to know whether "Thread-1" will eventually exit and then a new thread is created i.e "Thread-2" or still "Thread-1" would remain active. Pls help.

Comment: The thread will first call the function `hello` and then - after it completed - exit. This means that after the statement `t.start()` there are two threads active: the one which was just created and the "creator". After `hello` returned only one thread is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads will exit when they complete. In fact, as your print command is the last line in hello(), it means a thread exits as soon as it has displayed its name.  You can use `threading.enumerate()` to display all running threads:

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread, Timer, enumerate

def hello():
    print("hello, world")
    t = Timer(3.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print enumerate()
    print current_thread().name, "exiting" 

hello()
```

The only exception is the main thread, that does not exit but remains in stopped state until your program exits, which would never happen with this code but nevertheless. All other threads do their work and then exit.

Does this answer to your question?

Hannu

Comment: Yes it answers.. Thank you.